# ADC in python, change sampling time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, adc

I am new to python and also to raspberry pi, I have connected the High-Precision AD/DA Board to the RPI 3 model B, and I am looking to change the sampling time of the ADC and I am not sure if I need to change the RPI reading time as well, I have found some code such as

```
  byte drate_reg = 3; // Choosing Data Rate register = third register.
  byte drate_data = 0b11000000; // 11000000 = 3,750SPS
  SPI.transfer(0x50 | drate_reg);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);   // 2nd command byte, write one register only
  SPI.transfer(drate_data);   // write the databyte to the register
  delayMicroseconds(10);
```

However when I run the `sudo ./ads1256_test` to verify if it is properly reading, I am getting this random voltages that are not changing even though I have run with no error the line       `byte drate_data = 0b11000000; // 11000000 = 3,750SPS`. [The reading I am getting are:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhA3E.jpg)